# String extract from multiple columns using a list in R

Tags: r, string, text-extraction

I am trying to extract information from more than 2 columns (2 columns given as an example below) using a list and creating another column which contains the string from the list found from either one of the column specifying which column to look in first. I have the example below and what the desired output is. Hope that helps what I am exactly looking for.

```
A<-c("This contains NYU", "This has NYU", "This has XT", "This has FIT", 
"Something something UNH","I got into UCLA","Hello XT")
B<-c("NYU","UT","USC","FIT","UNA","UCLA", "CA")
data<-data.frame(A,B)

list <- c("NYU","FIT","UCLA","CA","UT","USC")

                        A    B
1       This contains NYU  NYU
2            This has NYU   UT
3             This has XT  USC
4            This has FIT  FIT
5 Something something UNH  UNA
6         I got into UCLA UCLA
7                Hello XT   CA
```

I would want the code to search from the list and look in column A first and if it cannot find the string then look in column B and if not then give null. By looking at the list, I would like the desired output to look like the below.

```
                        A    B    C
1       This contains NYU  NYU  NYU
2            This has NYU   UT  NYU
3             This has XT  USC  USC
4            This has FIT  FIT  FIT
5 Something something UNH  UNA <NA>
6         I got into UCLA UCLA UCLA
7                Hello XT   CA   CA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can transform your list to a regexpr and then apply R regexpr function :

```
expr <- paste0(list,collapse = "|")
# expr = "NYU|FIT|UCLA|CA|UT|USC" -> Reg expr means NYU or FIT or ......

data[,"C"] <- ""
cols <- rev(names(data)[-(which(names(data)=="C"))])

for(c in cols) {
 index <- regexpr(expr,data[,c])
 data[,"C"] <- ifelse(index != -1,substr(data[,c],index,index + attr(index,"match.length")-1),data[,"C"])     
}
```

Hope that will helps

Gottavianoni

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much!! Can you tell me what is happening inside the ifelse function. That would be super helpful

Comment: Ifelse fonction permits you to use if condition (if/then/else, without using boucle) on a list/df columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use library(tokenizers) from tokenizers package.

Merge two columns and create a new column with merged A and B

```
data$newC <- paste(data$A, data$B, sep = " " )
```

Then, follow below loop which will extract values in a vector and then u can cbind the vector in existing dataframe.

```
newcolumn <- 'X'

for (p in data$newC)
{
  if (!is.na(p))
{

x <- which(is.element(unlist(tokenize_words(list, lowercase = TRUE)), unlist(tokenize_words(p, lowercase = TRUE, stopwords = NULL, simplify = FALSE))))

    newcolumn <- append(newcolumn,ifelse(x[1]!= 0, list[x[1]], "NA"))
  } 
}

newcolumn <- newcolumn[-1]

newcolumn

data <- cbind(data, newcolumn)
```

Hope it helps. 
I am getting output of above as what you expected.

Solution Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```r
#common between column A & vector l
C_tempA <- sapply(df$A, function(x) intersect(strsplit(as.character(x), split = " ")[[1]], l))
#common between column B & vector l
C_tempB <- sapply(df$B, function(x) intersect(as.character(x), l))

#column C calculation
df$C <- ifelse(C_tempA=="character(0)", C_tempB, C_tempA)
df$C[df$C=="character(0)"] <- NA

#final dataframe
df
```

Output is:

```
                        A    B    C
1       This contains NYU  NYU  NYU
2            This has NYU   UT  NYU
3             This has XT  USC  USC
4            This has FIT  FIT  FIT
5 Something something UNH  UNA   NA
6         I got into UCLA UCLA UCLA
7                Hello XT   CA   CA
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(4L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Hello XT", 
"I got into UCLA", "Something something UNH", "This contains NYU", 
"This has FIT", "This has NYU", "This has XT"), class = "factor"), 
    B = structure(c(3L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("CA", 
    "FIT", "NYU", "UCLA", "UNA", "USC", "UT"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

l <- c("NYU","FIT","UCLA","CA","UT","USC")
```